# Cakephp 2.3: How to send an array of data to another controller function for rendering?

Tags: php, cakephp, controller

I have a controller action that is supposed to collect some preliminary information prior to user registration (head's up, I haven't hooked up auth yet, no one bug out on security plz!) and then redirect to the appropriate controller action, but I can't figure out how to pass an entire array of data. It's possible that I'm just too tired and I'm going to wake up to a facepalm here, but if anyone can set me straight I'd appreciate it.

```
public function register() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->request->url == "users/register") {
                $data = $this->request->data('Registration');
                switch($data['UserType']) {
                    case "student_reg":
                    /* I've tried this, and it feels right.. do have I to stop autorender or something? */
                        $this->studentReg($data);
                    break;
                    case "educator_reg":
                    /* and this: */
                        $this->redirect(array("action" => "educatorReg", "params" => $data));
                    break;
                    /* ... and so on.... */
                }
            }
        }
        $this->loadModel("Account");
        $accounts = $this->Account->find( 'all');
        $provinces = Hash::combine($accounts, '{n}.Account.province_id', '{n}.Province.name');
        $this->set(compact('accounts','provinces'));
    }

public function studentReg($data) {// and so forth
```

Comment: You should simplify your action, this much stuff going on will only get you in trouble in the long run. and do not expose methods as public (studentReg) if you plan on calling them internally. Or better make all that a model method you call. Try to keep the controller as clean, lean and readable as possible.

Comment: Well I really appreciate this sort of advice, but I'm not sure I follow it entirely. One thing to note is that the various soandsoReg() functions have views, they're essentially variations on add(). What I really need to achieve is just having had a user identify some things about themselves so they can be sent to the right page, with the caveat that if they can't, they won't be sent to any page at all, and this pre-identification doesn't get saved, it's just way to make sure their registration form is the right one. *Very* broadly, can you advise how you might implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just do `return $this->studentReg($data);` you should be fine. Cake shouldn't render another view if one has already been rendered.